# Excel DSUM() using Horizontal Range as input to Criteria

Tags: excel, vba, ms-office, excel-formula, excel-2010

I have a row of cells (criteria) in an Excel spreadsheet specifying the items that I need to "DSUM". e.g.

```
-----------------------------------------------------------
| Item Name   | Cash | Account Receivable | Common Stocks |
-----------------------------------------------------------
| Currency    | USD  | JPY                |               |
-----------------------------------------------------------
```

However, it seems that DSUM only accept column of cells as criteria. 
Is there any alternative way for DSUM to work with row criteria? or is there any other better way to do this? Thanks in advance.

My database is like below:

```
-----------------------------------------------------------
| Item Name     | Currency | Trn. Date | Amount  |
-----------------------------------------------------------
| Cash          | USD      | 3-10-2013 |  -10000 |
-----------------------------------------------------------
| Cash          | USD      | 3-10-2013 |  -20000 |
-----------------------------------------------------------
| Common Stocks | USD      | 3-10-2013 |  -10000 |
-----------------------------------------------------------
| Cash          | USD      | 3-10-2013 | 1000000 |
-----------------------------------------------------------
......
```

Answer (score 0):

Lets assume your data in `A2:D1000` and criteria table in `G1:J2` and that `Item Name` and `Currency` will be fixed in G1 and G2 respectively then you could use a `SUMPRODUCT` formula like this for the sum:

`=SUMPRODUCT(ISNUMBER(MATCH(A2:A1000,H1:J1,0)*MATCH(B2:B1000,H2:J2,0))+0,D2:D1000)`